# Run terminal operation on values in jq

Tags: json, base64, decode, jq

This is a simplification of my input:

```
[
  { 
    "Index": 1, 
    "Data": "aGVsbG8gaXRlbSAx"
  }, 
  { 
    "Index": 2, 
    "Data": "dGhpcyBpcyBpdGVtIDI="
  }
]
```

I need to replace the B64 encrypted data with the decoded text.

My command to decode an encrypted string looks like this:

`base64 -D <<< "aGVsbG8gaXRlbSAx"` or `echo "aGVsbG8gaXRlbSAx" | base64 -D`

How can I modify each `"Data"` value and then return the whole json file with jq?

Comment: @Dmitry this is some great functionality! Consider this [another plea](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/issues/7) for jtc on homebrew, as I intend to limit my dependencies to, and distribute my tool over, homebrew.

Comment: I'm working on the next version of `jtc`, once it's ready (eta is ~couple weeks), I intend to work on packaging `jtc` in homebrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jq` 1.6 can decode base64 data internally with the `@base64d` string formatter:

```
$ jq '[.[] | . + { Data: .Data | @base64d }]' input.json
[
  {
    "Index": 1,
    "Data": "hello item 1"
  },
  {
    "Index": 2,
    "Data": "this is item 2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can I do a similar replacement if the operation I want is not built into jq?

Answer (score 2):

In short:

```
map( .Data |= @base64d )
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I do a similar replacement if the operation I want is not built into jq?

Comment: Not easily, at least in general.  One approach that might not be obvious would be to use `jq --stream`.